# Folium map fail to render in notebook on github

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, folium

I try to upload my work to github with a folium map in python, but it fails to render the map as it should be on my PC.

Here is folium map shows on my PC:

[image]

Here is what I have on github, same notebook file:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that too.  Not sure whats going on.  Would something like http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ work?

Comment: Yeah, nbviewer works.

Comment: possibly related (please confirm if you can): https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4153

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [github help](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/working-with-jupyter-notebook-files-on-github):

> When you add Jupyter Notebook or IPython Notebook files with a .ipynb
>   extension on GitHub, they will render as static HTML files in your
>   repository. The interactive features of the notebook, such as custom
>   JavaScript plots, will not work in your repository on GitHub.

So, in short, interactive features of Jupyter notebooks like the `folium` maps won't be rendered when you add them in a github repository.

As a workaround, you can use [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1072). You just need to put the github link of your notebook in [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) and all your maps will be rendered there as they would normally be in a jupyter notebook.