# Make this notebook trusted to load map : File -> Trust Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, folium

```
import folium
world_map=folium.Map()
world_map
```

This is showing something like :
Make this notebook trusted to load map : File -> Trust Notebook 
while trusted is written on top right corner of my jupyter notebook file . How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61758219/3494126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general problem, I ran into the same issue a while back. What you have to do is to try changing your default browser to Chrome or Firefox it should work perfectly.

Comment: Yeah it's working . Thanks actually I was using Microsoft edge that's why it was not working it's working fine on Chrome.

Comment: What can I do if I'm using brave browser?

Comment: I did the same thing but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Got This same problem here on macOS Big Sur and Chrome is used.

Switch to Safari and the problem solved.