# Folium Map not displaying in PDF output

Tags: python, pdf, folium, weasyprint

I am trying to generate a PDF file from a Folium map using the weasyprint package in Python. I have the following code:

```
import folium
from weasyprint import HTML

def generate_map_html(lat: float, lon: float):
    """
    Generate a map HTML
    """

    # Generate map
    m = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon], zoom_start=15)

    # Add marker
    folium.Marker([lat, lon], popup='Property Location').add_to(m)

    # Save map to html
    map_html = m._repr_html_()

    return map_html

map_location = generate_map_html(33.589886, -7.603869)

html = HTML(string=map_location)

# save html to pdf
pdf = html.write_pdf()

with open('out/output.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pdf)
```

The PDF file is generated successfully, but instead of the map, I see the text "Make this Notebook Trusted to load map: File -> Trust Notebook".

How can I fix this issue and get the map to display in the PDF output?

The pdf output [image]

Comment: sounds like you are using jupyter and have to go to the menu "File" --> "Trust Notebook" in your notebook ... before running it.

Comment: i'm not using Jupyter notebook, this is just a standard python script

Comment: ok, hm, then I do not know ... one last guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245563/make-this-notebook-trusted-to-load-map-file-trust-notebook ..  try a different browser?

Comment: i already saw that stack overflow post, and i'm not using any browser, it a logic running in  a back-end application

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same problem

Comment: No i couldn't solve it, and couldn't find any solution online @LeonardoEsquivel